# How to display Image from ImageAnalysis.Analyzer?

Tags: android, opencv, android-camerax

So I'm new to Android programming and I'm trying to make an app that will process image in real time. I've implemented the Preview use case from [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/preview) as well as ImageAnalysis use case. At the moment the preview is displayed on a `PreviewView` but I'd like to process the image before displaying it so in short I'd like to do something with the frame in the `analyze()` method and then display this frame instead of the CameraX preview.

On a side note does using CameraX for such purpose even make sense? Eventually I'd like to use OpenCV for the processing but I went for CameraX because acquiring the image from camera was easy that way.

Comment: Hello,
I have the same case. I catch camera frames in `ImageAnalysis.Analyzer`, so I can process them through OpenCV. But quality of the image is bad, namely image color after conversion to RGB are not the same as I would use `androidx.camera.view.PreviewView` to display camera feed.
Does anyone have any suggestion how to improve image quality, so it will be like on `Preview`?

Answer (score 0):

Displaying the output of `ImageAnalysis` as preview should work, but the performance is going to suffer, especially if you are going to run it through OpenCV first. It's OK for prototyping, but I would not recommend it for a real product.

The output of `ImageAnalysis` is YUV_420_888. To display it, you can convert it to a `Bitmap` set it on an `ImageView`. See [this script](https://github.com/owahltinez/camerax-tflite/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/camerax/tflite/YuvToRgbConverter.kt). Where to do the conversion depends on the input/output format of you OpenCV library.